# Dreamweaver CS5 - CSS Website design tool

Tags: css

Is there a better CSS Website design/editor tool to design CSS Websites other than Dreamweaver that could be considered a great tool for a developer?

Thanks

---

Thanks for your answers.

I am an ASP.NET developer. I need an easy way (GUI-like) to design Websites layouts with pure CSS however I am not planning to master CSS as I cannot allocate time to that.

I haven't used Dreamweaver yet, I am just checking on the relatively easiest and best tool for css layouts.

Appreciate your help.
Regards

Comment: yes Notepad++ ;) A NON-GUI tool

Comment: Does it have to be WYSIWYG? Maybe you can tell us also why you're looking for another tool. Are you disappointed with Dreamweaver or do you just want to know what other tools people are using?

Comment: define 'better' and 'great' and 'developer'. Also mention OS and cost preferences. And details like what you are looking for in an IDE.

Comment: Don't use Dreamweaver, I got Dreamweaver CS6 and it takes 16% cpu while idle all the time :S Random crashes and not worth the money.

Comment: If it's C# why not just use Visualstudio, there is a free version (express) version

Answer (score 2):

If you're serious about front-end development, you shouldn't need anything more than a text editor with syntax highlighting for HTML, CSS and Javascript.

On Windows, [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) does a pretty decent job, another good option is [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/), especially for Javascript, although it can be a bit heavy weight depending on the job. I've also used [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) but not in any great depth, and then there's [Microsoft Expression Web](https://web.archive.org/web/20150528023952/http://www.microsoft.com:80/Expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx) which is very similar to Dreamweaver (I thought they had a free 'Express' edition but apparently not).

On Mac, as mentioned [CSSEdit](https://web.archive.org/web/20110923154710/http://macrabbit.com:80/cssedit/) is worth a look as is [TextMate](https://web.archive.org/web/20221208003521/https://macromates.com/) or [Coda](https://www.panic.com/coda/) or [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/). CSSEdit is squarely aimed at CSS, although to be honest the only feature I really use is sectioning with @group comments (I usually use TextMate for HTML and Javascript along side it).

Or for the hardcore on any platform there's [vim](https://www.vim.org/). Check out [vim casts](http://vimcasts.org) for some great tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mac use MacRabbit's [**CSSEdit**](http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/) its the best money i've ever spent :)

Also I would insist upon my stack:
[image]

Left-to-Right:

[Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/), [Billings](http://www.marketcircle.com/billings/), [CodeBox](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/codebox/id412536790?mt=12), [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/)(Just testing), [TextMate](http://macromates.com/), [CSSEdit](http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/), [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/), [Git Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/), [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/), [MAMP Pro](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/index.html), [MarsEdit](http://www.red-sweater.com/marsedit/)

All are non WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 0):

[BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org) has a free version and is very good at CSS3/HTML5